# Forgot AWS Organization Member Account IAM role name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

After setting up AWS Organizations, I created a member account with a custom IAM role name. I've now forgotten the role name used and I'm unable to [assume role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_accounts_access.html#orgs_manage_accounts_access-cross-account-role) as root into that account. I need to create IAM users in the member account but without the ability to assume role using the custom `OrganizationAccountAccessRole` it seems I'm unable to.

I've tried getting access by

1. Using the member account root user but it doesn't have permissions to IAM
2. Signing in to member account using AWS SSO user with `IAMFullAccess` and `AdministratorAccess` policies attached to the policy set but user cannot access IAM.
3. Attempting to describe member account using the master account admin user but the role isn't there

At this point, I'm thinking the only way out is to recreate the member account. Please tell me there is a better way.

---

UPDATE:
- Found that 1 & 2 didn't work because of a restrictive Service Control Policy (SCP) on the account which didn't include IAM access permissions.

Comment: If you creating the Org., can you use its master account to investigate this?

Comment: Hi @Marcin, I tried this i.e. #3 but role isn't returned when you view the account in the console or describe it in the CLI.

Comment: What about CloudTrial? Wouldn't it have any API calls logged which would be related to setting the role, and the role name?

Comment: @Marcin: Brilliant idea and it worked! I checked CloudTrail, filtered by `EventName:CreateAccount` and I was able to see the role specified in the `requestParameters`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear. I will make answer for future reference.

Comment: I was trying to switch and the switch page just reloaded without any error. Turns out I was signed in as the root user that is not allowed to assume roles. Maybe it helps someone who thinks they forgot the role name too. :-)

Comment: This is informative when considering the use of unconventional, distinct role names. From the management account's console, having distinct role names under "Role history" makes switching easy when compared to a list of identical role names to choose from. However, if the role name is forgotten, one may lose all access to the member account? Catastrophic, but perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The solution was to inspect `CloudTrial` logs to find the API call used to create the role.

Comment: This is a good solution if the account was created within the cloudtrail retention period.  If it's been more than a few months, though, it's no help.

Comment: @dannysauer Why? If your CT stores its logs in S3, you can inspect them any time for as long as you don't manually delete them.

Comment: Indefinite log retention isn't something people often do; usually there are a couple of lifecycle steps and then automatic deletion. Storage isn't free. :)